# How to increment number in a file

Tags: shell, sed, numbers, increment

I have one file with the date like below,let say file name is `file1.txt`:

```
2013-12-29,1
```

Here I have to increment the number by 1, so it should be 1+1=2 like..

```
2013-12-29,2
```

I tried to use 'sed' to replace and must be with variables only.

```
oldnum=`cut -d ',' -f2 file1.txt`  
newnum=`expr $oldnum + 1`
sed -i 's\$oldnum\$newnum\g' file1.txt
```

But I get an error from sed syntax, is there any way for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sed needs forward slashes, not back slashes.  There are multiple interesting issues with your use of '\'s actually, but the quick fix should be (use double quotes too, as you see below):

```
oldnum=`cut -d ',' -f2 file1.txt`  
newnum=`expr $oldnum + 1`
sed -i "s/$oldnum\$/$newnum/g" file1.txt
```

However, I question whether sed is really the right tool for the job in this case.  A more complete single tool ranging from `awk` to `perl` to `python` might work better in the long run.

Note that I used a `$` end-of-line match to ensure you didn't replace 2012 with 2022, which I don't think you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..:) I don't need awk here, as this is a small change. It is working well.

Comment: No problem; don't forget to pick your favorite reply and accept it by clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Sed does not need forward slashes, it needs a consistent separator. Backslashes just need escaping (doubling) in order to actually reach sed.

Answer (score 8):

usually I would like to use awk to do jobs like this
following is the code might work

```
awk -F',' '{printf("%s\t%d\n",$1,$2+1)}' file1.txt
```

Comment: @Jotne this gave me 1,1 for a file with the value '1' in it. I was not able to increment the number.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F, '{$2=$2+1}1' OFS=, file1.txt
2013-12-29,2
```

or more simply (this will file if value is `-1`)

```
awk -F, '$2=$2+1' OFS=, file1.txt
```

---

To make a change to the change to the file, save it somewhere else (`tmp` in the example below) and then move it back to the original name:

```
awk -F, '{$2=$2+1}1' OFS=, file1.txt >tmp && mv tmp file1.txt
```

Or using GNU awk, you can do this to skip temp file:

```
awk -i include -F, '{$2=$2+1}1' OFS=, file1.txt
```

Comment: @Jotne - fails on `...,-1`; better to keep the braces, and probably also to make output explicit: `awk -F, '{$2=$2+1;print}' OFS=, ...`

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Braces should be used yes, since `0` result would not be printed.  But as far as I know `{$2=$2+1;print}` would give the same as `{$2=$2+1}1'`.

Comment: @Jotne - correct, but the lone `1` me be overlooked (as a typo) to the uninitiated. Better to add a note explaining it in the answer.

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to add a double & between the commands.
awk -F, '{printf("%d\n",$1+1)}' nb.txt > nb2.txt && mv nb2.txt nb.txt
(note that the file just has a number)

Comment: it has to be `&&` and not `&` otherwise awk is in background and mv could be done when the file is not done.

Comment: @phschoen You are correct, fixed. Thanks   
In `Gnu awk` you can do `awk -i include -F, '{$2=$2+1}1' OFS=, file1.txt` to write without temp file.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner would be:

```bash
$ expr `cat /tmp/file 2>/dev/null` + 1 >/tmp/file
```

this works if the file doesn't exist or if the file doesn't contain a valid number - in both cases the file is (re)created with a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Bash one liner option with BC.  Sample:

```
$ echo 3 > test
$ echo 1 + $(<test) | bc > test
$ cat test
4
```

Also works:

```
bc <<< "1 + $(<test)" > test
```

Comment: I like the solution, but it doesn't seem to work because of a read-and-write at the same time conflict. i.e. "test" ends up empty.

Comment: What shell or bash version are you on? Works for me in v5.2.15.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is the best for your problem, but you can also do the calculation in shell

In case you have more than one rows, I am using loop here

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=,
while read DATE NUM
do
echo $DATE,$((NUM+1))
done < file1.txt
```